# javascript value returns undefiend in codeigniter view file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I have two view files.

1) `sign_up.php` and consists the validation code

```
<html>
....
....
<?php $this->load->view('frontend/common/footer.php'); ?>

<script>
alert(some_name); // Here I get value_defined
$('.register_form').validate({
...
...
submitHandler:function(form,e){
e.preventDefault();
....
alert(some_name); // Here I'm getting undefined
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

And my `footer.php` consists

```
var some_name = 'value_defined';
```

This is kinda weird for me. Did I made any mistake in the above code or why it's happening ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code looks correct because you get the value before validation script. May be you need to show your validation script code.

Answer (score 0):

Your footer.php consists the body and html tag and script too. No need to add into above html and body tag.

```
<script>
alert(some_name); // Here I get value_defined
$('.register_form').validate({
...
...
submitHandler:function(form,e){
e.preventDefault();
....
alert(some_name); // Here I'm getting undefined
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to have an unmatched closing `html` tag.